# Page not re-rendering when data is updated -- Vue.js

Tags: vue.js

Can't get why the app is not re-rendering when data is updated using method, can anyone see what's the issue? thanks!

On clicking the button, selectedPage is updating using the changePage method, but nothing is changing on the page (in the Vue dev tool I can see that selectedPage is changing correctly)

```
var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        showMain: false,
        isReader: true,
        selectedPage: [0,0],
        books: [
            {
            id: 0,
            name: 'איה פלוטו',
            image: 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/he/f/f3/%D7%90%D7%99%D7%94_%D7%A4%D7%9C%D7%95%D7%98%D7%95.jpg',
            pageList: [
                {id: 0, text: [',פלוטו כלבלב מקיבוץ מגידו','יש לו הכל, חלב ועצם','זה טוב ויפה, אבל בעצם','נמאס לו לשבת כך לבדו'], image: './images/wheres_pluto/page_1.jpeg'},
                {id: 1, text: ['lived a princes in a big castle'], image: './images/wheres_pluto/page_2.jpeg'},
                {id: 2, text: ['the END'], image: './images/wheres_pluto/page_3.jpeg'}
            ]
            },
            {
            id: 1,
            name: 'ספר שני',
            pageList:[]
            }
        ],
    },
    methods: {
        changePage: function(event){
            if(event == 'next'){
                this.selectedPage[1] = this.selectedPage[1] + 1
            } else {
                this.selectedPage[1] = this.selectedPage[1] - 1
            }
            console.log(this.selectedPage)
        }
    }
})
```

The html:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Heebo:wght@100;300;400;500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id='app'>

            <!-- book selection page -->
            <div class='page app-page' v-show="showMain">
                <div class='book-list' v-for="book in books" :book='book.name'>{{book.name}}
                    <img :src='book.image' />
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Book -->
            <div class="book" v-for="book in books" v-if='book.id == selectedPage[0]' :key=book.id>

                <div class="book-page" v-for="(page,index) in book.pageList" v-if='book.id == selectedPage[0] && book.pageList[index].id == selectedPage[1]'>
                    <!-- Video component  -->
                    <div class="video">VIDEO HERE</div>

                    <!-- Reader's page  -->
                    <div class="page reader-page" v-if="isReader" :key = page.id>
                        <div class="main-text" v-for='(lines,lineIndex) in book.pageList[index].text'>
                            <span>{{page.text[lineIndex]}}</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <!-- Kid's page  -->
                    <div class="page kid-page" v-else>
                        <div class="video">VIDEO HERE</div>
                        <div class="img-container" :style="{ backgroundImage: 'url(' + page.image + ')' }">
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <!-- controllers -->
                    <div class="controllers" v-if=isReader>
                        <button class="next" v-on:click='changePage("next")'>הבא</button>
                        <button class="prev" v-on:click='changePage("prev")'>קודם</button>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script> 
</html>
```

Comment: Try yo use v-show instead v-if in  <div class="book-page" v-for="(page,index) in book.pageList" v-if='book.id == selectedPage[0] && book.pageList[index].id == selectedPage[1]'>

Answer (score 0):

DTal, A couple of things to consider here. I noticed that you're using `selectedPage` for both the page number and the page ID. It may be simpler to map both of these to two separate variables.

The other thing to consider is that you may also want to bind what book is selected as well. Vuejs won't update the internals because it's already done the v-for loop. If you bind one of the divs (using `v-bind:`) to a book, and keeping track of which book is selected in the `data()` area then it may have the behavior you want.

Comment: Thanks! I'll give it a try. I'm yet at the beginning of my learning path :)

Comment: Good luck! I love Vuejs and I hope you learn to do so aswell, warts and all!

Answer (score 0):

There were a lot of things to be fixed in the template to make your code run but the main thing missing which was not making it run was that (copying directly from Vue documentation)

```
Vue cannot detect the following changes to an array:

    1. When you directly set an item with the index, e.g. vm.items[indexOfItem] = newValue
    2. When you modify the length of the array, e.g. vm.items.length = newLength

Change detection runs only for property mutations
```

Which can be achieved using

```
vm.$set(vm.items, indexOfItem, newValue)
```

which in your case would be

```
if (event === "next") {
    this.$set(this.selectedPage, 1, this.selectedPage[1] + 1);
} else {
    this.$set(this.selectedPage, 1, this.selectedPage[1] - 1);
}
```

I definitely feel that you can maintain the page numbers in a more efficient way(but that is a different concern)

Comment: Thanks! Appreciate your efforts to explain me the issue. As you can see, I'm an absolute  amateur, mostly doing projects for myself :)